# Apply Custom Plugin written as Groovy

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a written a Custom Plugin `CustomPlugin.groovy` and it is in the same path where my `build.gradle` resides. Refer screen shot below

[image]

Below is the code within my `CustomPlugin.groovy`

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply (Project project) {
        project.task('validate') {
            doLast {
                println 'Hi Validate'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I have this code within my `build.gradle` it works fine.. Whereas when i try to put this in a groovy-file, i get

`Could not get unknown property 'CustomPlugin' for root project 'gradle-play' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

How to have the plugins seperately as a Groovy-file in the same path as in build.gradle and then have these executed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to put the plugin you implemented in `buildSrc` folder. [Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources)'s is a very good documentation that describes it pretty well.